# Regex, match only the last one result

Tags: php, regex

Tried this , but no luck. Matches both results (see in example).

```
$lines = preg_grep("/1\.11\.\s\w*/m", $lines);
```

Example

```
1.11 Test
1.11 Test //other paragraph
```

Need only this to be found:

```
1.11 Test //other paragraph
```

Comment: ~20 minutes and no reaction for a regex question means the question is unclear. Please reformulate, provide sample input, output. A (non)working fiddle would be a nice-have. Note that `1\.11\.\s\w*` really matches both results, there is nothing surprising here.

Comment: `preg_grep` is not the right function to use here... and your `regex` doesn't match either line actually.

Comment: did some changes in the post

Comment: if you only want to match the last line the `regex` could simply be `@/@`... is $lines an `array`, `string`? `preg_grep` is generally used for arrays.

Comment: Is $lines an array? Do you need a string as output?

Comment: @stribizhev: That's what you are supposed to figure out apparently o_O Think of it as a puzzle type of question, or riddle perhaps.

Comment: @l'L'l: The floor is yours, if you wish :) I have already stumped into this with another question.

Comment: Yes, $lines is an array.

Comment: @stribizhev: Thanks, but I'm bad at reading minds :p

Comment: Try [`$lines = preg_grep('~1\.11\s*\w+\s*//~', $lines);`](https://ideone.com/nPQ6ub).

Comment: Tought you are Severus Snape ;//

Comment: Does it mean I can post that :)?

Comment: @l'L'l: I am not that fan of Harry Potter, but that is really funny! :) Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead. Optionally, preg_match can store matching character sequences in an array, then you can pick the last element of that array.

```
$result = null;
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/1\.11.+/';
$string = "1.11 Test
  asd 123
  1.11 Test //other paragraph
  asda";
$tmp = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

if ($tmp === 1) $result = end($matches);

unset($matches, $pattern, $string, $tmp);
var_dump($result);
```

Your regexp pattern will also fail, because the second dot (\.) will never match.

Comment: It works fine on http://phptester.net/ . So I think it will work on your local php install too.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input `$lines` is an array and you seem to want to get the items that start with `1.11` and contain a word and then a comment, you can use

```
$lines = preg_grep('~^1\.11\s*\w+\s*//~', $lines);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/RN8SFW)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - start of string
- `1\.11` - literal `1.11`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace symbols
- `\w+` -  1 or more word (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) symbols
- `\s*//` - zero or more whitespace symbols followed by a literal character sequence `//`